# Selenium Python | Wait for Entire Page to Load, Not Dependant on a Dynamic Element

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, data-science

I've seen similar questions to this but no one has given me a clear answer on whether or not it is possible for Selenium to know whether the entire page has loaded or not.

I know about `expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "div"))` but I **do not** want a dynamic element to look for. I also don't want to wait a set number of seconds, I need the program to continue as soon as the entire page is loaded.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium **webdriverWait**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
```

In the code above, Selenium will wait for a maximum of 10 seconds for an element matching the given criteria to be found. If no element is found in that time, a *TimeoutException* is thrown.

Or you can use the **time** module:

```
import time 
time.sleep(10)
```

In the code above the program will wait for 10 seconds before executing the next line.